# How to do flow type annotations for React hooks (useState, etc.)?

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

How should we be using Flow type annotations with react hooks, such as `useState`? I've tried searching for some examples of how they should be implemented, but can't find anything.

I tried this:

```js
const [allResultsVisible, setAllResultsVisible]: [ boolean, (boolean) => void, ] = useState(false);
```

Which doesn't throw any flow related errors, but I'm not sure if this is correct or the best way to annotate the hook. If my attempt isn't correct or the best way, what should I do instead?

Comment: Ideally, *Flow* should infer the types from `useState(false)` (like TypeScript does), and wouldn't need  annotations at all.

Comment: Use type arguments `const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Flow infers the types, as [shown in the PR](https://github.com/facebook/flow/pull/7149/files#diff-2404896722ab82fc5a3973309bde093a) that added support for hooks to the Flow library.

**UPDATE**

As discussed in my comments of another answer, the resulting variables must be used contextually for the type-checking to work as expected.

```
const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);
(loading: boolean);

setLoading('foo') // Flow error
```

vs.

```
const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);

setLoading('foo') // no Flow error
```

Comment: You can also use type arguments `const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);`

Answer (score 3):

Type inferring doesn't work for me:

```
const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true) // boolean
setLoading('foo') // no Flow error
setLoading(1) // no Flow error
```

Had to add typings manually:

```
const [loading, setLoading]: [boolean, ((boolean => boolean) | boolean) => void] = React.useState(false)
setLoading('foo') // Flow error
setLoading(1) // Flow error
```

I have:

```
"react": "16.8.6",
"flow-bin": "0.100.0",
```

#### UPDATE

As @AndrewSouthpaw pointed, `loading` has to be used in some context or `setLoading` won't work correctly.

This works:

```
const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);
(loading: boolean);

setLoading('foo'); // Flow error
```

The same without semicolons:

```
 const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true)
 ;(loading: boolean)

 setLoading('foo') // Flow error
```

**ESLint**

ESLint [no-unused-expressions](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-expressions) will give an error from this. eslint-plugin-flowtype has fixed version [flowtype/no-unused-expressions](https://github.com/gajus/eslint-plugin-flowtype#eslint-plugin-flowtype-rules-no-unused-expressions).

Comment: It appears you need to use that `loading` in some context, otherwise `setLoading` won't work correctly. https://flow.org/try/#0FAAglgtgDg9gTgFxAJQKYEMDGSBmcYQgDkcG2RA3MKJjAHYDOSA2rQK50IA0IDqCAYRgcEAXRABeFGQQA6NnwDKCdAlQAKAIwBKKqHXtOALhB02EAEao4ukAHo7IAPIBrHhbZIEcAJ4haEBConGB0AOYgCAAWYAwgADahqCDCSOh0ACaRUcnW+HApdAlJIAAcIGEwqHHoAO7oPtR8gsKc6t5sqLYOIACicPkmFjAw8RhFseB0AVCqYBZjILVg0abmVnDAQA

Comment: How can you share Flow examples via "Try Flow": https://flow.org/try/? Didn't find any sharing functionality from the site.

Comment: You can share via Try Flow by copying the URL that is generated in the browser.

Answer (score 3):

If the type can be inferred from the initial value, no need to add typing information for Flow, for example:

```
const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
```

If it can't be inferred because the initial value is a complex object, use generics to assign a type, for example:

```
type Merchandize = {|
  name: string,
  value: number,
|};

const [shoppingCare, setShoppingCart] = React.useState<Array<Merchandize>>([]);
```

Comment: Oh my, I was looking for this, thank you for the answer. This solved my Flow useState type issue!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers above,

Make sure you put `// @flow` at the very top of your file, to make all flow features working fine.

The only one solution which worked for me without putting `// @flow` at the top was:

```
const [allResultsVisible, setAllResultsVisible]: [ boolean, Function ] = useState(false);
```