# "ReferenceError: string is not defined" in React useState with flowjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype, flow-js

I'm trying to annotate useState(null) with flow but getting the error `ReferenceError: string is not defined`.

I'm doing something like:

```
const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState<string | null>(null)
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Error at runtime?

Comment: yes at runtime. flow doesn't throw errors but the app breaks with this error

Comment: Sounds like types are not erased. Is it happing only with specific file?

Comment: anywhere I define such a syntax then this happens

Comment: Have you configured @babel/preset-flow or something that will remove the types?

Answer (score 0):

The `useState<string | null>` is a TypeScript syntax. If you're not using TypeScript just use `useState(null)`

Comment: what about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55977991/how-to-do-flow-type-annotations-for-react-hooks-usestate-etc it says I can use what I'm doing now?

Comment: Did you use the flow annotation `// @flow` ?

Comment: Specifying generic type explicitly seems to work fine https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChS0IA7AZ3gG1QUBzJAVSgBsAaOGpGAEkQLdlwC6cALyJiMAHQBXfgGUYKGEgA8dKMCrM4AHzhVFnTgD4AFGYsBKUkA

Comment: I added `// @flow` and that's why the rest of my app is working fine. Just when I try to use it with useState as you see it's not working